# Algunas dudas con docker y rocketchat

Tags: docker

Estoy poniendo en marcha un servidor de Rocketchat con Docker en un VPS con Plesk. Me he metido recientemente en el mundo de Docker y tengo algunas dudas sobre problemas que me han ido surgiendo:

- Para tener Rocketchat funcionando he seguido un tutorial bastante bien explicado desde el cual a través de un archivo docker-compose realizo la configuración para luego poner en marcha 3 contenedores: uno con mongodb, una replica de este contenedor de mongodb (para mejorar el rendimiento según he visto) y otro contenedor con la instalación de Rocketchat. El caso es que si borro estos contenedores, junto con sus imágenes, volúmenes y networks y vuelvo a realizar la instalación desde cero, los datos que tenía anteriormente en Rocketchat siguen estando y no me pide ni realizar una configuración inicial ni nada, directamente los datos persisten. ¿Qué es lo que me estoy perdiendo? Puesto que si he borrado tanto los contenedores como sus volúmenes, ¿no deberían de existir datos anteriores no?
- Otro tema que me tiene mareado es que al realizar la instalación cogiendo como ROOT_URL un subdominio que he creado previamente desde Plesk (con su certificado SSL), habilitando Nginx y creando una redirección de proxy de "/" al puerto 3000 para el contenedor de Rocketchat, me da error 502 bad gateway nginx al acceder desde https://chatdominio.com:3000 pero si accedo desde http://chatdominio.com:3000 accede correctamente.

¡Un saludo!

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un enlace al tutorial que has seguido para ver cómo configura las cosas? Sin esa información sólo podemos intentar adivinar. Por ejemplo, para la primera pregunta, es posible que monte como volúmen una carpeta del sistema de archivos (y no un volumen docker). Para la segunda es posible que la redirección al puerto 3000 no esté "terminando SSL", sino que le esté mandando el tráfico cifrado, y que el gatweay no sepa descifrarlo o no tenga acceso a los certificados.

Comment: El tutorial que he seguido es este: https://kenfavors.com/code/how-to-install-rocketchat-on-ubuntu-16-04-using-docker-docker-compose/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Sobre la persistencia de datos

Examinando el `docker-compose.yaml` que utiliza [el tutorial que has seguido](https://kenfavors.com/code/how-to-install-rocketchat-on-ubuntu-16-04-using-docker-docker-compose/) puede verse que varios de sus servicios montan carpetas locales como volúmenes en el contenedor. Por ejemplo:

```
services:
  rocketchat:
    image: rocketchat/rocket.chat:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./uploads:/app/uploads
    ...
```

Como se observa tras `volumes:`, se usa la carpeta local `./uploads` como volúmen a montar dentro del contenedor, en `/app/uploads`. Por tanto, aunque borres todos los contenedores docker, cuando lances de nuevo la imagen rocketchat usando este docker-compose, lo que internamente verás en `/app/uploads` dentro del contenedor será de nuevo lo que hubiera en tu carpeta `./uploads`. Esta carpeta por tanto "sobrevive" a reinicios del contenedor, borrados de su imagen, etc. Naturalmente puedes borrar esta carpeta local si quieres que el próximo arranque del contenedor comience con esa carpeta vacía.

Lo mismo ocurre con la base de datos, pues puede verse que el servicio mongodb también monta una carpeta local dentro del contenedor:

```
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
     - ./data/db:/data/db
    ...
```

En este caso la carpeta local `./data/db` se monta en el contenedor en `/data/db`. En el primer arranque esa carpeta estará vacía, por lo que mongodb creará los ficheros necesarios en ella para guardar la base de datos. En subsiguientes arranques, ya que la carpeta persiste al estar almacenada en el sistema de ficheros del anfitrión, mongodb ya no la encontrará vacía, y por tanto no creará bases de datos nuevas sino que usará la que allí haya.

## Sobre SSL y nginx

Sería necesario ver qué configuración de Nginx has escrito para esta parte, pero lo más probable es que estés redireccionando el tráfico a algo como `https://tu.dominio.registrado:3000/`, lo que fallaría porque le estás enviando al backend el tráfico cifrado y éste no está preparado para ello. O quizás lo estás reenviando a `http://tu.dominio.registrado:3000/`, lo que "terminará" la conexión SSL y hará una nueva no cifrada entre nginx y el backend, pero podría fallar porque este backend no esté preparado para escuchar en la IP pública, sino solo en localhost, o porque un cortafuegos impida el acceso al puerto 3000 desde la IP pública.

Lo que creo que debería funcionarte sería redirigirlo a `http://localhost:3000` (asumiendo que rocketchat está ejecutándose en la misma máquina que nginx, y que el contenedor hace visible su puerto 3000).

Comment: Todo solucionado, gracias por la magnifica explicación.